# Multiple file sending over to a server

Tags: c#, windows, file, service, transfer

I have made a windows service the motive behind is to send multiple files to a designated server.

```
       private void sendfile()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        RegistryKey theLocalMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey theSystem2 = theLocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\NetworkUsagemonitoring\\", true);
        RegistryKey interfacekey4 = theSystem2.OpenSubKey("Usagerecorder", true);
        string serverno = interfacekey4.GetValue("serverno").ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < netarr1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < netarr2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (netarr1[i].Name == netarr2[j])
                {
                    IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverno), 5656);
                    Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                    try
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(@"C:\" + netarr1[j].Name + "_record.xml"))
                        {
                            fileName = (@"C:\" + netarr1[j].Name + "_record.xml");
                            fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
                            while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
                            {
                                filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                            }
                            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
                            if (fileNameByte.Length > 850 * 1024)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
                            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

                            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
                            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
                            clientSock.Send(clientData);
                            clientSock.Close();
                            recorded[j] = 0;
                            File.Delete(@"C:\" + netarr1[j].Name + "_record.xml");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Update1Network_Interface();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.Message == "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")
                        {
                            LogEvent("No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (clientSock != null)
                        {
                            LogEvent("Client Socket Closed", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                            clientSock.Close();
                            sendfile();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        restart();
    }
```

But as this service file start its execution..there seem to be three files which needs to sent to the server but it tends to send only one constantly neglecting the other one...As in the code snippet under the two for loops i am checking the existence of the files and if they are present then they need to be transmitted.

As in the server side  for a testing purpose following was the code

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FTServerCode.receivedPath = (@"C:\Receiving\");

        if (FTServerCode.receivedPath.Length > 0)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
}
class FTServerCode
{
    IPEndPoint ipEnd;
    Socket sock;
    public FTServerCode()
    {
       ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
       sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
       sock.Bind(ipEnd);
    }
    public static string receivedPath;
    public static string curMsg = "Stopped";
    public  void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            curMsg = "Starting...";
            sock.Listen(100);

            curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5120];

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
            curMsg = "Receiving data...";

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath +"/"+ fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            curMsg = "Saving file...";

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
            StartServer();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            curMsg = "File Receving error.";
        }
    }
}
```

What i want is to check the existence of files and transmit them to the server and if there is an error then the file should be re transmitted....

Any help will be highly acknowledged.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a first glance, you are using netarr1[j].Name in the inner loop... should that be netarr1[i].Name (or netarr2[j].Name since you are only executing when they are equal)??

Maybe i and j are hard to distinguish in text, maybe a more descriptive naem

Also System.IO.Path.Combine is good to use on file paths....

Comment: initially i had netarr1[i] then i changed it to j but no luck in any of the cases

Comment: actually the files are being generated correctly these seems to some problem during transfer, as when initially the first file is transferred then on the server side it received then closes the socket and again starts listening and in between this i guess the either files tend to get the error message as the file transfer failed and only the first file in the loop tends to get transmitted to the server..

Comment: I actually can't see why you have 2 loops - at the moment, if I understand correctly you seem be just processing the contents of netarr2 in the "for j" loop , but doing it netarr1.Length times. I can't see any varying input from netarr1 (i.e. the outer, i, loop) at all.  Can you give a quick summary of the intended logic?  I really would check that the file names you are using are the ones you expect (add trace code). Thereare lots of good functions for parsing and constructing file paths and names in the System.IO library. I find these save me making errors in "home grown" code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the i and j think...had a few faults while placing my i and j variables...as i can draw the conclusions there some problem to my server side code...as my service file is working perfectly...and now only problem is my server side is able to receive one file...as my service app tend to send multiple file over to server side...do i need to create a TCP async listener or the code already listed will work out ?